# Creating a class object to be used globally in Python

Tags: python

I wrote the module below that will standardize how my logfiles are written as well as easily changing whether events get printed/written to the logfile or not.

```
FILE: Logging.py
================
import os
import datetime
import io

class Logfile():
        
    
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.logFile = os.getcwd() + r'\.Log\\' + name + '_' + str(datetime.date.today().year) + ('00' + str(datetime.date.today().month))[-2:] + '.log'
        self.printLog = False
        self.debug = False
        
    # Setup logFile and consolidated Folder
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(self.logFile)):
            os.mkdir(os.path.dirname(self.logFile))
        #Check if logfile exists.
        if not os.path.exists(self.logFile):
            with open(self.logFile, 'w') as l:
                pass
        

    # Write LogFile Entry
    def logEvent(self, eventText, debugOnly): # Function to add an event to the logfile
        # If this is marked as debugging only AND debugging is off
        if debugOnly == True and self.debug == False:
            return
        if self.printLog == True:
            print(datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%m/%d/%Y, %I:%M:%S %p, ') + str(eventText))
        with open(self.logFile, 'a') as l:
            l.seek(0)
            l.write(datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%m/%d/%Y, %I:%M:%S %p, ') + str(eventText) + '\n')
            return
```

This is very handy but, I am having trouble understanding how to make this available to all of my classes. For example, If i import the following module, I am not sure how to use the logfile i created within my main script.

```
FILE: HelloWorld.py
===================
class HelloWorld():
    def __init__(self):
        log.logEvent('You have created a HelloWorld Object!', False)
```

Main Script Here:

```
import Logging
from HelloWorld import HelloWorld

log = logging.Logfile
hw = HelloWorld()
```

^^ Will fail because it does not know log is a thing. What is the proper way to handle these sort of situations?

Comment: On a side note, why are you re-inventing the wheel? `import logging`

Comment: As DeepSpace said, there is already that module, you can create function that sets all parameters with your desire and just use it or import. If you really want global module, you should try to install it with `pip install -e .` to do that you need to specify setup.py

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're trying to do something like this.  (and as a side note, you may want to look into using pythons default logging module)

```
FILE: HelloWorld.py
===================
# import LogFile
from .Logging import LogFile
# create new LogFile instance
log = LogFile(name='log name')

class HelloWorld():
    def __init__(self):
        # call logEvent method on your LogFile instance
        log.logEvent('You have created a HelloWorld Object!', False)


FILE: Main.py
===================
# import HelloWorld
from .HellowWorld import HellowWorld
# create new HellowWorld instance
hw = HellowWorld()
```

Also, to create a module you will need to add an `__init__.py` file in that given directory.

Comment: if ```class HelloWorld():``` is in another module, then it will throw an exception unless i pass ```log``` into it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is easily solved by using the built-in "Logging" module. In an answer to the broader "how to use a thing(log) within all of my modules" question, I assume the answer to this can be found by reading through the code in the logging module and mimicking that.